# How to do a collision detection without pygame?

Tags: python

I've tried different methods but I can't seem to figure it out I am trying to make a inserted image have a collision detection with getMouse.

```
from graphics import *
from playsound import playsound
import time

## Graphing frame 1. 
win1 = GraphWin('Fram.1', 640, 360) # Give number of frames and dimensions of window.
win_1 = Image(Point(320, 180), r"/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Win1.png")
start_button = Image(Point(320, 210), r"/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/StartButton.png")
win_1.draw(win1)
start_button.draw(win1)
start_button.getMouse()
win1.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'collision detection'? Because nothing in that code looks remotely related to collision detection.

Comment: You may want to revise your question and include specifically what the problem is, what you have tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: If you don't want to use a library, you do it yourself. For axis-aligned rectangles, it's easy (just consider the X and Y bounds and see if they overlap). For arbitrary convex polygons, it's [harder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) but still doable. For general (potentially concave) shapes, I recommend praying your deity of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**I found an answer to my own question instead of using pygame I made an invisible 
rectangle where if I click in that rectangle it closes the window.** 


from graphics import *
from playsound import playsound
import time

**Graphing frame 1.**
win1 = GraphWin('Frame.1', 640, 360) # Give number of frames and dimensions of window.
win_1 = Image(Point(320, 180), r"/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Win1.png")
start_button = Image(Point(320, 210), r"/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/StartButton.png")
rect1 = Rectangle(Point(320, 210), Point(310, 220))
win_1.draw(win1)
start_button.draw(win1)
               
while True:
    clickPoint = win1.getMouse()
    x = clickPoint.getX() - rect1.getCenter().getX()
    y = clickPoint.getY() - rect1.getCenter().getY()
    rect1.move(x,y)
    print ("x = {} y = {}".format(rect1.getCenter().getX(), rect1.getCenter().getY()))                 

    if (rect1.getCenter().getY() > 201 and
        rect1.getCenter().getY() < 217 and 
        rect1.getCenter().getX() > 251 and
        rect1.getCenter().getX() < 388 ):
        win1.close()
        break
```